# Integrating files from both the original repo and a secondary fork

Tags: git, github

I have a proper newbie question for git/ github, so my apologies. I am at that stage where I am still learning *what* to google - although google I did. And a lot. I promise.

I am forking multiple repositories associated with a larger project and pulling them all into a central Github organisational account.

One of the repositories I have forked has two scripts that I want to keep. A second user has also forked this repository, deleted the original files and created three new files. I want my fork to contain all five files.

I found this, which enables me to pull the three new files into my forked repo: https://help.github.com/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork/  but when I do this, it deletes the two original files.

Both repos haven't been updated in nearly a year (the original project is now complete, so this is more an exercise of capturing it's legacy). If there are any tips on how I can maintain updates in *both* the origional repo and the fork I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If multiple people are forking and contributing to a same repository you can push your changes to remote master via PR. 
Once other guy has pushed the changes to remote repo you can take a pull from remote and then you can blame your changes so that guy will come to know what changes he can't override.
Moreover if you want to ignore his changes you can cherry pick specific commit from remote